# What does "aMultiTable[i]" do and what is it for?

Tags: arrays, lua

This is the code used to create a multi dimensional code in lua and I dont understand what aMultiTable[i] = {} means and what it does.

````
for i = 0, 9 do
  aMultiTable[i] = {}
  for j = 0, 9 do
    aMultiTable[i][j] = tostring(i) .. tostring(j)
  end
end ```
````

Comment: Lua has an excellent manual and intro book, give https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html a read, your question is addressed in https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html

Answer (score 0):

```
aMultiTable[i] = {}
```

creates a new empty table in the table `aMultiTable` at index `i`

This is very very basic Lua. If you want to know how something works, read its manual!

From [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual: 3.2 Variables:](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.2)

> Square brackets are used to index a table:
>
> `var ::= prefixexp ‘[’ exp ‘]’`

From [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual: 3.4.9 Table Constructors:](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9)

> Table constructors are expressions that create tables. Every time a
>   constructor is evaluated, a new table is created. A constructor can be
>   used to create an empty table or to create a table and initialize some
>   of its fields. The general syntax for constructors is
>
> `tableconstructor ::= ‘{’ [fieldlist] ‘}’`

I'll leave researching the assignment operator to you...